Spliting a list of names into First and Last name list is not working
I am making a scraper that scrapes names. The list that I get is this one (under variable names_clean):
['Andy El-Bayeh', 'Bryan Philips', 'Rodney Ferro', "Jimmy L'almont", 'Andrew Thorn', 'Laurie Patton', 'Sharyn Grant', 'Jake Bertone', 'Nathan Reiche', 'Anthony James', 'Sasko Bosilkovski', 'Aimee Brown', 'Dan Sim', 'Allan Dib', 'Boyd Roberts', 'Jeremy Liddle', 'Danny', 'Bhavin Bagadia', 'Alexis Fenton', 'Simon Marmot', 'Jules Lund', 'Shane Lavagna-Slater', 'Stuart Phipps', 'Yvette Adams', 'Terry Wilson']

and the code for it is this one:
names = soup.find_all('div', class_='zp_xVJ20')
names_clean = [name.find('a').text.strip() for name in names]

I want to split this list into two list:

First name list
Last name list

I have tried the foillowing but I keep getting list lenght of 24 and it should be 25 (missing one name):
names = soup.find_all('div', class_='zp_xVJ20')

first_name = []
last_name = []

for name in names:
    anchor = name.find('a')
    if anchor:
        full_name = anchor.text.strip()
            
        if len(full_name) == 1:
           first_name.append(full_name)
        else:
           split_name = full_name.split(' ', 1)  # Split at most once
        if len(split_name) > 1:
           first_name.append(split_name[0])
           last_name.append(split_name[1])

What could be the problem? Also if you have a better and simpler solution please write it.
Thank you.

I'd be tempted to add an else  after the if len(split_name) > 1 check and print out anything that doesn't get appended. I also see the clean names using find('a') in your initial words, and one name doesn't have a 'a'.

Note that if len(full_name) == 1: is always False since its checking if the full_name is only a single character.  It's not the correct check for only having a first name.

@doctorlove I did add else in the end because one of the names doesn't have a last name.

The logic of your code is wrong, because you check if the length of the full name is equal 1 before splitting, which is practically always wrong (hardly we can find someone whose name is just a single letter). So this always ends with splitting, and then you add names to the lists if only splitted data consists of 2 items. This way you miss the name 'Danny' from you examples.
As an alternative to the possible solution by @DarrylG, I'd suggest using the itertools.zip_longest:
from itertools import zip_longest

names = (name.text.split(maxsplit=1)
         for name in soup.find_all('div', class_='zp_xVJ20')
         if name.find('a'))

first_name, last_name = zip_longest(*names, fillvalue='')

It works correctly with empty strings and single names.

p.s. Just as an experiment:
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from itertools import zip_longest

target_class = 'zp_xVJ20'
other_class = 'something'

html_doc = f"""
<html><body>
<div class={target_class}><p> A part with no links </p></div>      <!-- no links -->
<div class={other_class}><a> This must be skipped </a></div>       <!-- different class -->
<div class={target_class}><a> Antoine de Saint-Exupéry </a></div>  <!-- 3 parts -->
<div class={target_class}><a>  </a></div>                          <!-- empty name -->
<div class={target_class}><a>Andy   El-Bayeh</a></div>             <!-- 2 parts -->
<div class={target_class}><a>Danny  </a></div>                     <!-- 1 part -->
</body></html>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
names = (name.text.split(maxsplit=1)
         for name in soup.find_all('div', class_=target_class)
         if name.find('a'))
first_name, last_name = zip_longest(*names, fillvalue='')

print(f'{first_name=}\n{last_name=}')

Output:
first_name=('Antoine', '', 'Andy', 'Danny')
last_name=('de Saint-Exupéry', '', 'El-Bayeh', '')


You could do it like this to deal with single word names:
def split_name(name, n=2):
    """ Splits name into exactly n (>=2) parts, padding with empty strings """
    parts = name.split(maxsplit=n-1)
    return parts + [""] * (n - len(parts))

first, last = zip(*(split_name(name) for name in names))


Would suggest the following modification which:

Provides first and last name if both exists
Makes the last name '' if it doesn't exists

Code
names = soup.find_all('div', class_='zp_xVJ20')

first_name = []
last_name = []

for name in names:
    anchor = name.find('a')
    if anchor:
        full_name = anchor.text.strip()
        split_name = full_name.split(' ', 1)
        first_name.append(split_name[0]) # always a first name
        if len(split_name) > 1:
          last_name.append(split_name[1]) # last name exists
        else:
          last_name.append('')  # use '' as last name


IMO as far as this is about the html page with possible duplicated spaces between words, it may be reasonable to use full_name.split(maxsplit=1). This way we need no stripping and any contiguous sequence of spaces will be used as a single divider.

@Vitalizzare -- isn't split_name = full_name.split(' ', 1) using your suggestion?

No. If there is more than 1 space between two parts, full_name.split(' ', 1) will keep all but the first space in the second part. So on the next step you'll need to strip() them just to be sure there are no leading spaces.

Assuming you don't have to cater to the possibility of middle names, you could just use two list comprehensions here:
first_names = [x.split()[0] for x in names_clean]
last_names =  [x.split()[1] for x in names_clean]


Does this work with one name? e.g. Madonna or Prince?

Does this work if the name has a middle component?  No.  Nobody listens to Madonna or Prince anymore, so is your question even valid?

Fair enuf. I wonder why OP went to the bother of doing if len(full_name) == 1:

You missed 'Danny' in the list of possible names.

In the case of "Antoine de Saint-Exupéry" the surname is "de Saint-Exupéry". However, in the case of "Francis Ford Coppola" the surname is "Coppola". I'm just making the point that naive splitting doesn't necessarily produce the desired result. Also... Pelé
